# Make 2 subset vectors so that values are different index-wise

Tags: r, vector, indexing, subset, element

I want to make 2 vectors subsetting from the same data, with `replace=TRUE`.

Even if both vectors can contain the same values, they cannot be the same at the same index position.

For example:

```
> set.seed(1)
> a <- sample(15, 10, replace=T)
> b <- sample(15, 10, replace=T)
> a
 [1]  4  6  9 14  4 14 15 10 10  1
> b
 [1]  4  3 11  6 12  8 11 15  6 12
> a==b
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

In this case, vectors `a` and `b` contain the same value at index 1 (value==4), which is wrong for my purposes.

Is there an easy way to correct this?

And can it be done on the `subset` step?

Or should I go through a loop checking element by element and if the values are identical, make another selection for `b[i]` and check again if it's not identical *ad infinitum*?

many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My idea is, instead of getting 2 samples of length 10 with replacement, get 10 samples of length 2 without replacement

```
 library(purrr)
 l <- rerun(10,sample(15,2,replace=FALSE))
```

Each element in `l` is a vector of integers of length two. Those two integers are guaranteed to be different because we specified `replace=FALSE` in `sample`

```
 # from l extract all first element in each element, this is a
 a <- map_int(l,`[[`,1)
 # from list extract all second elements, this is b
 b <- map_int(l,`[[`,2)
```

Comment: That's really clever. `split(replicate(10, sample(15,2)), seq(2))` would be a base R replication of a similar method.

Comment: @fmarm Oh yes, that's clever indeed. Should be much faster than my approach. Very neat!  (+1)

Comment: I like this idea, but I have a question... would it be possible to do it with `replace=TRUE`? As in all values across `a` should be different and all values across `b` different as well? I would probably need to have that option

Comment: @DaniCee if you need all different values it's actually easier, just do for example `v <- sample(25,20,replace=TRUE) ` so you get a vector with 20 different values , and then cut it in two pieces `a <- v[1:10] ; b  <- v[11:20]`

Comment: @fmarm sorry I was confused, I wanted to say `replace=FALSE`

Comment: So the thing is now I need 2 vectors `a` and `b` and every value in `a` must be different, and every value in `b` must be different as well. Then every value for the same index must be different between `a` and `b`

Comment: @DaniCee that’s what I also understood, but I put replace=TRUE instead

Comment: But the problem is I always need to sample from a vector `1:15`, I cannot take a sample of 20 and then divide in 2 vectors

Comment: you get what I mean? So from a given sampling vector (`1:15` in the example), I need 2 vectors (`a` and `b`) of 10, so that every value in each of them is different (`replace=F`), and for the same index, the value between `a` and `b` is different too

Comment: Hi @fmarm please check the new question I just opened if you can, I think I do need replacement=FALSE... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58375977/r-make-2-subset-vectors-so-that-values-are-different-index-wise-and-also-diffe

Answer (score 3):

How about a two-stage sampling process

```
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:15
a <- sample(x, 10, replace = TRUE)
b <- sapply(a, function(v) sample(x[x != v], 1))
a != b
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

We first draw samples `a`; then for every sample from `a`, we draw a new sample from the set of values `x` *excluding* the current sample from `a`. Since we're doing this one-sample-at-a-time, we automatically allow for sampling with replacement.

Comment: Hi @MauritsEvers please check the new question I just opened if you can, I think I do need replacement=FALSE... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58375977/r-make-2-subset-vectors-so-that-values-are-different-index-wise-and-also-diffe