# Make 2 subset vectors so that values are different index-wise, and also different across each vector

Tags: r, indexing, subset, element

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58370234/r-make-2-subset-vectors-so-that-values-are-different-index-wise), I want to do something similar, but this time I have one more requirement.

I want to make 2 vectors subsetting from the same data.

I need `replace` to be set to `FALSE` because I need all values to be different across `a`, and all values to be different across `b`.

Apart from that, values cannot be the same in `a` and `b` for the same index position.

Note that sampling vector `v` is always fixed, as is the sample length `l`.

Doing the following, I only fulfil one criterium (values across `a` and values across `b` are different, but still values in the same index between `a` and `b` can be identical)

```
> set.seed(1)
> v <- 1:15
> l <- 10
> a <- sample(v, l, replace=F)
> b <- sample(v, l, replace=F)
> a
 [1]  4  6  8 11  3  9 10 14  5  1
> b
 [1]  4  3  9  5 13 12  7  8 14 10
> a==b
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Doing the following (answer from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58370234/r-make-2-subset-vectors-so-that-values-are-different-index-wise)), I only fulfil the other criterium (values in the same index are not identical, but there can be identical values across `a` or `b`).

```
> ab <- split(replicate(10, sample(15,2)), seq(2))
> a <- ab[[1]]
> b <- ab[[2]]
> a
 [1] 14  7 10  8  2  6  6  8 13 12
> b
 [1]  5  5  4 11 13 12  5 13  6 14
> duplicated(a)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> duplicated(b)
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Any help trying to collapse both approaches? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Edited with a `while` loop to do the resampling until it is correct (with no duplicates).

Got it... What I did was check which values in `b` are equal to `a` for the same index, and which are not equal.

For those that are equal, I resample from a vector equal to `v` but without the already "accepted" values in `b` (the ones not equal to `a` for the same index).

Like this:

```
> set.seed(6)
> v <- 1:15
> l <- 10
> a <- sample(v, l, replace=F)
> b <- sample(v, l, replace=F)
> a
 [1] 10 14  4  5  9 15 11  7 13  1
> b
 [1] 10 13  2  4  9  3  5  6 14 11
> a==b
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE


> if (any(a==b)==TRUE) {
+   b0 <- b[which(a==b)]
+   b2 <- b[which(a!=b)]
+   vnew <- v[which(!(v %in% b2))]
+   b0 <- sapply(b0, function(x) sample(vnew[vnew != x], 1))
+   while (any(duplicated(b0))==TRUE){
+     b0 <- sapply(b0, function(x) sample(vnew[vnew != x], 1))
+   }
+   b[which(a==b)] <- b0
+ }


> a
 [1] 10 14  4  5  9 15 11  7 13  1
> b
 [1] 15 13  2  4 12  3  5  6 14 11
> a==b
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> duplicated(b)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Still not quite there yet, cause it can happen that the new `b0` values are identical...

Comment: Edited with a while loop to do the resampling until it is correct (with no duplicates)